# Why if condition is executing

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing simply inserting in database (mysql) .I have put a conditional if statement to test whether my insert query is executing or not. I found that my entries are going into the database very well but that test If condition which I have put gives me error which shows that my query is not executing and reality is query is executing .Here is the code

The form `

```
    <form action="?ref=login_insertNews" method="post">

        <tr>
            <td><label>News Title</label></td>    <td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>News description</label></td>    <td><textarea cols="26" rows="6" name="dcp"/></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Date</label></td>    <td><input type="date" name="dat"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>   <td><input class="button" type="submit" value="POST" name="POST"/></td>
        </tr>


    </form>

</table>`
```

this code is my controller code (i am doing in MVC)

```
public function login_insertNews() {          
    if(isset($_POST['POST'])){
        $result= $this->mlogin->insert_news($_POST);
        if($result){
            echo 'success';
        }
        else {
            echo 'error';    
        }
        echo $_POST['title'];
        echo $_POST['date'];
        echo $_POST['dcp'];     
    }
 }
```

here is my Model(database) code

```
public function insert_news($_POST) {

        $this->insert_query="insert into `_news` (`_news_title`,`_news_detail`,`_news_status`,`_news_date`) VALUES('" .$_POST['title'] . "',
                                                                        '" .$_POST['dcp'] . "',
                                                                                                1,
                                                                                         '" .$_POST['dat'] . "')";



        return $this->insert();

    }
```

In insert query i want to have value of _news_status as 1 .Did i put it right or I should wrap like '1'

Comment: Can `$this->mlogin` return more information about the actual error?

Comment: no molgin is object which have created in a constructor in same class like this parent::__construct($class);
$this->mlogin = new mlogin(); so it can be available in all functions of controller

Comment: We need to see the code for the `insert()` to understand why it is returning a false value

Comment: @Munim its a framwork , i will provide the code to you here it is the code :protected function insert() {

        $status = $this->conn->query($this->insert_query); // mysql_query($this->insert_query);

        if ($status != 1) {
            $this->gene_error();
        }
    }
i am not sure you wil get it fully

Comment: So, there's no way to get more detailed information about the error that occurred? Which framework do you use?

Comment: @VolkerK its name is CodePetrol ,its similar to codeIgnitor

Comment: @Snow_ash Your code is showing `error`.But you need `success`.is that?

Comment: we will launch it soon , i am using it for testing purpose

Comment: @som you got right i want that success if should be executed , and also know what mistake i have made

Comment: @Snow_ash You need to check your `$this->insert` method.It retuns null.after insert you can return `insert id`

Comment: @som i have used  the same approach before, it works but not now , i guess i have make some little mistake so the resut is coming false

Answer (score 0):

```
public function insert_news($_POST) {
if(!empty($_POST)){
//your insert query here
 }
}
```

Comment: @RoneyMichael Mr som have got right  what i was asking, you should scroll his comments ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="POST" name="POST"/> //here you use value="POST" this is quiet confusing use other word like value="submit" 




    public function login_insertNews() {
                if(!empty($_POST) &&  isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['dcp']))
                or 
                 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $result= $this->mlogin->insert_news($_POST);
                    if($result){
                        echo 'success';
                    }else {
                        echo 'error';    
                    }
                    echo $_POST['title'];
                    echo $_POST['title'];
                    echo $_POST['dcp'];
                }
          }
```

Comment: you have mention isset($_POST['title'] twice and you mean isset($_POST['dcp']

Answer (score 0):

check what value is in $result. If it is failing the If condition it must be zero or false or maybe null:

```
$result= $this->mlogin->insert_news($_POST);
var_dump($result);die();
```

Comment: that means
  
    $this->mlogin->insert_news($_POST);

either it is NOT inserting the record or it is inserting the record and the method does not return anything on success. Look at the insert_news() code.